# Sharepoint list, conditioanlly displaying icon

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

hope you are doing well. I am currently trying to custom format a list using JSON. I am having trouble conditionally displaying the "Attach" or paperclip icon depending on whether the field attachment link (i.e [$attachment_x0020_link]) is empty or not.

Below is the relevant code snippet and a the current look of the list

```
{
    "elmType": "a",
    "attributes": {
      "iconName": "=if([$attachment_x002d_link] != '', Attach)",
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "[$attachment_x002d_link]"
    },
    "style": {
      "font-size": "15px",
      "padding-top": "15px",
      "cursor": "pointer"
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is `attachment link` custom column you created in list? Or you are trying to read values from SharePoint default attachments column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using JSON formatting. First of all, Attachments to a list item is an array of 1 or more objects, but you couldn't get hold of that property using @currentField.
If you are planning to use Classic view, then you can probably get the attachments using REST API and use JS Link. This JS Link [code snippet](http://blog.binarybits.net/programming/sharepoint/display-attachments-using-jslink-in-sharepoint/) can help you to form your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If attachment link custom column you created in your list, try using condition for `iconName` like below:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "=if([$attachment_x002d_link] == '', '', 'Attach')",
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "[$attachment_x002d_link]"
  },
  "style": {
    "font-size": "15px",
    "padding-top": "15px",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  }
}
```

Where `attachment_x002d_link` is internal name of your SharePoint list column. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

The attachment field is [$Attachments], and you can check whether it is populated by comparing it to 1 or 0:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "=if([$Attachments] == '0', '', 'Attach')",
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "[$attachment_x002d_link]"
  },
  "style": {
    "font-size": "15px",
    "padding-top": "15px",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  }
}
```

Using the above, you should be able to at least get the icon to appear correctly.

However, it is not possible to get the file names/links directly using JSON.  You might be able to find a potential workaround here: [How can I add a link to list attachments using Json formatting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304996/how-can-i-add-a-link-to-list-attachments-using-json-formatting)